# Link cypress video to test results in release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm setting up a cypress test in my release pipeline. In my release pipeline I run these npm commands:

```
"test": "cypress run --spec cypress/integration/localAuth-spec.js",
"ci": "nuxt generate -s && start-server-and-test start-server http://localhost:3000 test",
```

The tests run and with the `publish test results` I'm able to publish the results to the test tab in the release:

[image]

In my cypress.config I export the videos and I can see that happening in the release pipeline log. But I'm wondering how I can link the video to the test.

Comment: If there's no builtin functionality: Azure DevOps provides an API to upload Test Result and Test Run attachments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0.

Answer (score 0):

In the pipeline, we can not link the video to the test. We can output the videdos and then attach the videos to the workitem. This might be the work around.

Comment: Would it be better to do the testing in the build proces?